# insert data from multiple tables into temp table

Tags: sql-server

```
--Receive_Amount Having Column
________________________________________________
PID    Head             Receive_Date    Amount
------------------------------------------------
1001   consumeable       12/8/2011        20,000
1001   Manpower          12/8/2011      1,00,000
1001   Travel            13/8/2011        40,000
1001   Travel            18/8/2011        10,000
1001   consumeable       5/09/2011        10,000

--Second Table
--Expenditure Table
PID    Head             Exp_Date    Amount
------------------------------------------------
1001   Travel           13/8/2011    2,000
1001   consumeable      13/8/2011    5,000
1001   Travel           18/08/2011   1,000

--And Third Table
--Advance Table Having Column
_____________________________________________
PID    Head             Adv_Date    Amount
---------------------------------------------
1001   Travel           14/08/2011   3,000
```

i want to insert Data from these 3 tables into Temp Table

```
___________________________________________________________________________
PID  Trans_Date   Head       Head_Balance     Exp_Amount    Running Total
___________________________________________________________________________
1001   13/8/2011  Travel        40,000         2,000           2,000
1001   13/8/2011  consumeable   20,000         5,000           7,000
1001   18/08/2011 Travel        48,000         1,000           8,000
```

Comment: What's your problem and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I need to write all queries, then create a temp table,but where is your code?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what values from the source tables need to go to the temp table (I can't see anything from **PID Head Adv_Date Amount** that is needed in the output), any business logic you need, and an example of what you've tried and/or what is not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union` if the different tables looks the same.

```
select * from Receive_Date Amount
union all
select * from Exp_Date Amount
union all
select * from Adv_Date Amount
```

Comment: Being that the output example has 3 numeric fields at the end, the output structure is not the same as the input structure.